# Couldn't find option to create followup intent through API

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am looking for an API (NodeJS) to create follow-up intent in dialogflow ES edition.
Can somebody help me? I want to create inbuilt follow-up intent.

I could find some option to read follow-up intent details of existing intents in https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent

But couldn't find an API to add inbuilt follow-up intent to my intent.